# Very simple but working drush extension?

Tags: drush

I want to implement my own [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush) command, and struggle because while the ["Make me a sandwich" example](http://api.drush.ws/api/file/examples/sandwich.drush.inc/4.x/source) is very good, it's also quite complex, and for someone that has never made such an extension it's easy to loose track of what is mandatory, and what is optional.

I would like to see a basic Drush extension implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is valid for Drush >= 4

```
<?php
/**
 * @file EXAMPLE.drush.inc
 * Provides a simple drush extension example
 */

function EXAMPLE_drush_command() {
  return array('COMMANDNAME' =>
    array(
      'description' => 'My example command',
      'bootstrap' => DRUSH_BOOTSTRAP_DRUSH,
    ),
  );
}

function drush_COMMANDNAME_validate() {
  // Return
  // drush_set_error('MACHINE_NAME_OF_FAIL', dt('Command failed because [reason]'));
  // on error.
}

function drush_COMMANDNAME() {
  echo 'Extension working!';
}
```